# You have to draw 10 cards. What is the probability you will not drawn any repeated cards?

Tags: probability

Assume you have 52 cards in a deck, and you have to draw 10 cards. Assuming you have to put back the card after each draw, what is the probability that you will not draw ***any*** repeated cards?

Here's what I was thinking...

- Draw 1: $\frac{52}{52}$ since first card is allowed to be any card.
- Draw 2: $\frac{51}{52}$ since you don't want to draw the first card,
  you're now allowed to draw 51 of the remaining cards.

  ...
- Draw 9: $\frac{44}{52}$ since you don't want to draw the last 8
  cards, you're now allowed to draw 44 of the remaining cards.
- Draw 10: $\frac{43}{52}$ since you don't want to draw the last 9
  cards, you're now allowed to draw 43 of the remaining cards.

So $\frac{52}{52} \times \frac{51}{52} \times ... \times \frac{44}{52} \times \frac{43}{52} = 0.397$ or $39.7\%$ chance of not getting a repeat.

Just wanted to check if this is the correct approach to the problem or not.

Comment: This is correct.  Notice, that the complement is that "you will have drawn at least one repeat" is a rephrasing of the famous [birthday problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's *a* correct approach, yes.   It's a bit long winded, but it clearly shows you know what you're doing.   Naught wrong with it.

More compactly:   The size of the favoured space ($S$) is: ${^{52}\mathrm P_{10}}$ ways to select $10$ different cards from $52$ and then arrange them in some order.   The size of the total space is: $52^{10}$ ways to select any $10$ cards (with allowed repetitions, in some order).   All distinct ways so counted have an equal weighting.

Thus the probability is: $\qquad \mathbb P(S)=\dfrac{52!}{42!\, 52^{10}} \approx 0.39{\small 7} $

Which is what you got.

Comment: Thanks for the lesson and notation.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is correct! I had the same approach and answer when solving this problem.