# You have to draw 10 cards. What is the probability that you will draw at least one repeated card?

Tags: probability

Assume you have 52 cards in a deck, and you have to draw 10 cards. Assuming you have to put back the card after each draw, what is the probability that you will draw at least one repeated card?

Here's what I was thinking...

- Draw 1: $\frac{52}{52}$ since first card is allowed to be any card.
- Draw 2: $\frac{1}{52}$ since you want to try to draw the first card.

  ...
- Draw 9: $\frac{8}{52}$ since you want to try to draw one of the last 8 cards.
- Draw 10: $\frac{9}{52}$ since you want to try to draw one of the last 9 cards.

So $\frac{52}{52} \times \frac{1}{52} \times ... \times \frac{8}{52} \times \frac{9}{52} = 1.31 \times 10^{-10}$ or $0\%$ chance of getting at least one repeat.

Is this the correct answer?

Comment: Hint: think in terms of complementary probability instead: what's the probability of not drawing a repeated card in all of your ten draws?

Comment: This is the complement of the event that you asked yesterday [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1308718/you-have-to-draw-10-cards-what-is-the-probability-you-will-not-drawn-any-repeat).  The answer would be one minus the probability calculated there as per http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle

Comment: Don't forget to use your intuition to consider whether your answer is reasonable. The probability of drawing 10 cards and repeating at least one of them is certainly greater than $.000000000131$!

Comment: How do you put back the cards?  How do you select the next card?  If you put back the cards at the bottom and you select the next card from the top, then the probability that you will draw at least one repeated card is zero.

Answer (score 2):

This problem is probably a lot easier to do complementarily. Clearly, there are 52**10 ways to draw 10 cards with replacement.

How many ways can we draw all different cards? Well, I draw one card, and now I am forced to draw a different card, so I end up getting Perm(52, 10) or 52*51*50*...*43, or 52!/(52 - 10)!.

This gives me (52!/42!)/52^10 = 4312477756125/10859007357952 is approximately 0.397133698686279352048390186651011083048135138024492577807237. So remove that from 1 to get approximately 0.61 something or other as your chance that you will draw at least one repeat.

Comment: You are dividing your number of permutations by $52^{10}$ because that's how many "decks" there are, yes?

Comment: Well, that's the number of /draws/ there are. You can certainly think of it as drawing from 10 separate decks. It's to the 10th power because you are using replacement after each draw. In other words, when you draw with replacement, the cardinality of your sample space is 52^10. If you didn't replace, it would of course be a factorial, if that makes sense.

Comment: Gotcha. It does make sense since the deck would be reduced by one after each draw.